# Nginx (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I get this error after setting up nginx with this digital ocean tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

My system:
Nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu 16.04, django 1.8

my nginx.conf

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80  ipv6only=on;
    server_name comparebet.co.ke www.comparebet.co.ke;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/error.log;
}

server  {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name comparebet.co.ke;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass https://app_server;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/error.log;
}
```

error

```
2017/03/22 04:32:31 [error] 26108#26108: *763 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 178.62.11.22, server: comparebet.co.ke, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "https://178.62.11.22:443/", host: "comparebet.co.ke"
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `proxy_pass` back to the same nginx server? Shouldn't you be passing to Django instead?

Comment: Resolved it, but still same error involving ssl..can't communicate with django / gunicorn

Comment: You don't need to talk https to your app server, you can talk http. https to the app server can be advantageous in some situations. You need to make it clear where the error is happening, browser to nginx, nginx to app server, etc. We need more information if you want help.

Comment: If I use http, I end up in a loop with the first server block above..problem is nginx to app server..I did this at first

Comment: So you used `proxy_pass http://app_server` in your configuration and it ended up in a redirect loop? What exactly does the redirect loop look like in CURL output?